# Unable to add com.facebook.share.widget.Sharebutton to Layout XML

Tags: android, share, facebook-sdk-4.0

I am trying to use Facebook SDK in Android to [Share Content](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/android) Direction from my app.

I'm using the following code from here on [Facebook Docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/android):

```
ShareLinkContent content = new ShareLinkContent.Builder()
    .setContentUrl(Uri.parse("http://www.focusoutdistractions.com/"))
    .build();

    ShareButton shareButton = (ShareButton) rootView.findViewById(R.id.ibtn_twshare);
    shareButton.setShareContent(content);
```

**Question is** - In the XML file, I need to add *com.facebook.share.widget.Sharebutton* to the XML but it is not getting recognized.

Is *com.facebook.share.widget.Sharebutton* the correct XML element to add for this Sharebutton?

Comment: have you added Facebook library in your project ?

Comment: Yes, I have no problem with the Java Code (the library imported OK), just in XML I dont see it popping up.

Comment: Ok, sometimes xml is unable to render custom View. Try to run this in your actual device or emulator. Tell me if this help :)

Comment: Do as Ajeet said, even Login button is not recognized by XML but runs perfectly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add this line in the main layout

```
xmlns:facebook="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
```

like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:facebook="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
```

Answer (score 5):

Yes, `com.facebook.share.widget.ShareButton` is correct XML element. It will not be rendered by preview of XML layout, but don't worry about it. The app will compile without problems, and running app will show it properly.

```
<com.facebook.share.widget.ShareButton
        android:id="@+id/shareButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="5dp" />
```

[image]