# Facebook share button Android

Tags: android, facebook

I want to add facebook share button in my Android app. I already have a button which is working fine and my posts are going to facebook corectly. But now I'm using a standard android button and I want to replace him by facebook share button:

[image: 1]

I have add to my layout xml file lines:

```
<com.facebook.share.widget.ShareButton
    android:id="@+id/shareButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

The problem is, when I want to open post to share my app is crashing.

I have add line:

```
xmlns:facebook="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
```

Like in [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29340092/unable-to-add-com-facebook-share-widget-sharebutton-to-layout-xml) but still the same.

Comment: use this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38759057/share-score-on-facebook-android

Comment: I have working share button. I want only to use facebook share button instead of standard android button.